# Seeking a WordPress Solution for Conditional Form Display during Multiple File Downloads

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hubspot-cms

On my WordPress website, I have a page with multiple digital files available for download. I would like to set up a system such that when a visitor clicks on a download link, a form (from HubSpot or any WordPress form plugin) appears for them to fill out. Once they submit the form, the file automatically downloads.

However, if the same visitor decides to download another file, I'd like to bypass the form since their information has already been captured from their initial form submission. In this case, clicking the download link for the second file (or any subsequent files) should initiate the download immediately, without displaying the form again.

I've been struggling to find a solution for this scenario. Are there any specific plugins or combination of plugins for WordPress that can accomplish this?